# Последовательный вывод изображений Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, spyder

Как можно сделать последовательный вывод изображений в Spyder? На данный момент получается вывести только последнее изображение

```
img_5 = imread('C:/abc1.png')
imshow(img_5)

img_6 = imread('C:/abc2.png')
imshow(img_6)
```

Comment: ``C:///.png`` что за странное имя файла?

Comment: Это не ошибка, просто для вопроса исправил. Суть в том, что идут два imshow() подряд, но выводится только последний

Comment: Немного исправил. Пример выше выводит только последнее изображение

Comment: думаю, что последнее изображение выводится поверх предыдущего и затирает его, нужно указывать, что изображения должны выводиться не на все окно, а рядом друг с другом, как обычно делается в похожих пакетах

Comment: Хорошо, а не подскажете, как это сделать?

Comment: Не, я с scikit незнаком. Думаю, у imshow есть какие-то параметры для этого

Comment: функция `imshow()` есть и в `matplotlib` и в `OpenCV` (`cv2`) - которую из них вы используете?

Comment: использую scikit-image

Comment: Покажите ваши импорты библиотек. Откуда вы импортируете `imshow` в частности?

Answer (score 4):

[Пример из документации - выводим две картинки на одном холсте](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/data/plot_specific.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from skimage import data

matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 18

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
ax = axes.ravel()

images = data.stereo_motorcycle()
ax[0].imshow(images[0])
ax[1].imshow(images[1])

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю в `scikit-learn` нет функции `imshow`, зато она есть в `matplotlib.pylab`, например. Если вы используете всё-таки `matplotlib`, то можно между картинками указать `matplotlib`, что вы хотите рисовать на новом изображении:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

...

img_5 = imread('C:/abc1.png')
imshow(img_5)

# новое отдельное изображение
plt.figure()

img_6 = imread('C:/abc2.png')
imshow(img_6)
```

Comment: Вот импорт библиотек ```from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imsave```

Comment: @aleksandr А, ну это не совсем `scikit-learn`, я бы сказал. Хотя и связанная с ним библиотека.

Comment: Ну да, я выше писал, что это scikit-image

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread, imshow

img_5 = imread('C:/abc1.png')
plt.imshow(img_5)
plt.show()

img_6 = imread('C:/abc2.png')
plt.imshow(img_6)
plt.show()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]